# Why use DOMStringList rather than an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

I've recently discovered the [DOMStringList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMStringList), which can be found in an [IndexedDB's list of store names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBDatabase/objectStoreNames). It seems like a DOMStringList is just a simplified version of an array, which has only two methods `item()` and `contains()`. There is no useful methods like `indexOf`, `filter`, `forEach` that you'll find on an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#array_methods_and_empty_slots). Why use this kind of object? What are DOMStringList's advantages?

Comment: My assumption is that they're more efficient for DOM strings under the hood (such as the guarantee of all elements being a DOM string as opposed to having to be able to store `any`thing), and JavaScript doesn't convert it to a less efficient Array unless you explicitly tell it to

Comment: it maybe because array includes method wasn't always supported but DOMStringList has been around since chrome version one.

Answer (score 21):

The existence of `DOMStringList` is a historical accident. Today, in modern APIs, the same use cases are met by using an `Array` instance.

It was introduced into web APIs because we needed something array/list-like, that cannot be modified. The "cannot be modified" part is important, because there's no good answer for what would happen to a modifiable array in scenarios like

```js
db.objectStoreNames.push("foo");
db.objectStoreNames.push(notAString);
db.objectStoreNames.shift();
```

At the time the first API using `DOMStringList` was introduced, the people designing the API did not know how to make this work with `Array`s. So, they designed `DOMStringList`. It was used for a couple of APIs, namely `location.ancestorOrigins` and `db.objectStoreNames`.

But then, the people designing such web APIs figured out how to introduce non-modifiable arrays. This actually took two separate tries:

- Introducing the use of [frozen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) `Array` instances, via the [`FrozenArray<>`](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#idl-frozen-array) [Web IDL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/WebIDL) type. See [whatwg/webidl#52](https://github.com/whatwg/webidl/pull/52), and the linked bug there.
- Introducing the use of [proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) around `Array` instances, via the [`ObservableArray<>`](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#idl-observable-array) Web IDL type. See [whatwg/webidl#840](https://github.com/whatwg/webidl/pull/840), and the linked bug there.

The difference between these two is that frozen `Array`s cannot be modified, even by the browser; whereas proxies around `Array`s can be modified by the browser. (Or even by the web developer, if the spec in question allows that.)

So, can we move everything using `DOMStringList` to use one of these modern solutions? No. Because there is code in the wild which depends on `db.objectStoreNames.item()` and `db.objectStoreNames.contains()` working, and that would break if we moved to actual `Array` instances, which don't have those methods.

So we might need a *third* `Array` wrapper type if we want to fully obliterate the legacy array-like classes from the web platform, and start using true `Array`s. It would be a subclass of `Array`, with an extra method or two, and possibly a proxy wrapped around that. Nobody has yet made moves in that direction.

(Other legacy array-like classes, you say? Yes: in addition to `DOMStringList`,  we have `TouchList`, `AnimationNodeList`, `CSSRuleList`, `DOMRectList`, `FileList`, ... see [this list of classes on the web platform with an `item()` method](https://dontcallmedom.github.io/webdex/i.html#item()%40%40TouchList%40method), most (but not all) of which are of this sort.)